# How to compare consecutive elements in two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, comparison

I have two arrays  all with unique  values  and I want to compare them  so that I get a list of all the  values that consecutive

```
const array1 = [1a,4a,3h,78h,5b,6b,7h]
const array2 = [3h,1a,4a,5b,6b,7h]
```

In this case I want to compare any number of consecutively  matching values
I want a list of all the pairs or any number of consecutively matching unique values they have  which then gives me a list  like this

```
const array3 =[[1a,4a],[5b,6b,7h]]
```

what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you explain why the expected result is `[[1a,4a],[5b,6b]]`?

Comment: because they are consecutive   so  in both the arrays 1a and 4a  are followed by each other  and in the second one 5b and 6b are followed by eachother so they create their own array too   if that makes any more sense  a

Comment: Will they always be pairs? what if `[5b,6b,7b]`? is this `[5b, 6b], [6b, 7b]` or ...

Comment: no it can be any number as long as they are consecutive  so it could from as small as a pair to as big as  both arrays could manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetchValues = (array1, array2) => {
let result = [[]];

let loop = (i, j) => {
    if (i >= array1.length || j >= array2.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
        
        result[result.length - 1].push(array1[i]);
        loop(++i, ++j);
        return;
    }

    let nextIndex1 = array1.indexOf(array2[j], i);
    let nextIndex2 = array2.indexOf(array1[i], j);


    nextIndex1 = nextIndex1 < 0 ? Infinity : nextIndex1;
    nextIndex2 = nextIndex2 < 0 ? Infinity : nextIndex2;


    if (nextIndex1 !== Infinity || nextIndex2 !== Infinity) {

        result[result.length - 1].length === 0 || result.push([]);
    
        nextIndex1 > nextIndex2 ? loop(i, nextIndex2) : loop(nextIndex1, j)
    }

}
loop(0, 0);
const finalresult= result.filter(array=>array.length>1)
return finalresult;
}
```

This is the way I got it work for me if any one has another way then please  feel free to share

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is (there should many better), first to create all the possible subarrays:
eg:
const array1 = [1a,4a,3h,78h,5b,6b,7h]
const array2 = [3h,1a,4a,5b,6b,7h]

const subArray = [[1a,4a],[3h], [5b,6b,7h]]

once you have the subarray, you can map them to a new array with their Max location in either array with respect to subarray:

const maxLocation = [[1,2][2][4,5,6]];
Now you need to find the longest in sequence => [[1,2][4,5,6]]

Comment: hey @vaira his solution does works for this example arrays given but not for all  examples  for example 

`const arr1 = ['1a', '4a', '3h', '78h', '5b', '6b', '7h']
const arr2 = ['1a', '5b', '6b', '7h']
`
 would output `[ [ '1a' ], [ '5b', '6b', '7h' ] ]`

Comment: I am not sure about the new answer, since I don't have enough time in hand to test it out myself